# How to return a value from a void closure in Swift?

Tags: swift, google-app-engine

I have a function that queries a certain user in order to access an array of that user. I returns the user and I can access their array. However, the call is asynchronous and what is being returned is nil. The function over all has a completion handler, however, inside there is a query call and by default that query returns Void.

```
    func _getAllMatches(completionHandler: ((UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)!) -> Int{
    var toReturn = [GTLUserUser]()
    let query = GTLQueryUser.queryForUserList()
    query.userBucket = "messages-20-messagestabletes-1465782960"
    service.executeQuery(query, completionHandler: {(ticket, response, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil{
            self._showErrorDialog(error)
            return
        }
        else{
            let userCollection = response as! GTLUserCollection
            if let newUsers = userCollection.items() as? [GTLUserUser]{
                toReturn = newUsers
                completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData)

            }
        }
    })

return toReturn[0].likedArray.count
}
```

How do I wait for this query to return and assign to "toReturn" so that it will actually return something instead of returning nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's an asynchronous method, you cannot return the value, but instead follow the completion handler pattern, including the data returned as a parameter:

```
func performAllMatchesQueryWithCompletionHandler(completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult, [GTLUserUser]?, ErrorType?) -> ()) {
    let query = GTLQueryUser.queryForUserList()
    query.userBucket = "messages-20-messagestabletes-1465782960"
    service.executeQuery(query) { ticket, response, error in
        guard error == nil else {
            completionHandler(.failed, nil, error)
            return
        }

        if let userCollection = response as? GTLUserCollection, let newUsers = userCollection.items() as? [GTLUserUser] {
            completionHandler(.newData, newUsers, nil)
        } else {
            completionHandler(.noData, nil, nil)
        }
    }
}
```

I infer from your use of `UIBackgroundFetchResult`, that you're doing a background fetch. If so, your `performFetchWithCompletionHandler` might look like so:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    performAllMatchesQueryWithCompletionHandler { fetchResult, users, error in
        switch fetchResult {
        case .failed:
            // do whatever you want if there was an error

        case .noData:
            // do whatever you want when there is no data

        case .newData:
            // do whatever you want with `users`, presumably updating your model or what have you
        }

        completionHandler(fetchResult)
    }
}
```

You could then call this method from `viewDidLoad` or wherever appropriate for your app.

Note, I removed the leading underscore on the method names, as that's not a common convention in Swift, but call your methods whatever you want. And I renamed `_getAllMatches` to `performAllMatchesQueryWithCompletionHandler`, as it makes it more clear that you're performing an asynchronous query.

---

In comments, you say that you're not doing background fetch, but rather are populating a table. So you might do something like:

```
func retrieveDataForTableView(tableView: UITableView) {
    performAllMatchesQueryWithCompletionHandler { fetchResult, users, error in
        switch fetchResult {
        case .failed:
            // do whatever you want if there was an error

        case .noData:
            // do whatever you want when there is no data

        case .newData:
            // do whatever you want with `users`, presumably updating your model or what have you

            // once you've updated your model, you can reload the table:

            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Note, I've assumed that this completion handler is running on the main thread. If not, you'd want to `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { ... }` the code that updates the model and calls `reloadData`.

Personally, I wouldn't be inclined to use `UIBackgroundFetchResult` for my `performAllMatchesQueryWithCompletionHandler` if I wasn't really doing background fetch. I'd probably use my own enumeration for that, to avoid any confusion regarding the intent of this code.

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I think this is what I am looking for, however, how do I call that func application(application: UIApplication....?

Comment: Perhaps I inferred too much from your use of `UIBackgroundFetchResult`. That is used when your app issues background fetch requests. And that is triggered when the OS calls `performFetchWithCompletionHandler` on your app delegate. So you don't call that method, but rather the OS does. But if you're not doing background fetch, then you wouldn't use `UIBackgroundFetchResult`. So, are you doing background fetch or not?

Comment: Yes I am. What I am trying to accomplish is have a table view in my view controller load with the number that query returns. Say I query for a list of users and I get back 3. I want my numberOfRowsInSection function to return 3. However what it is doing is calling the query async and not returning the correct number. It doesnt matter to me if it is in the background or not. I would just like it to be called every time the view loads.

Comment: I understand. You just call `reloadData` in the completion block. See my revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an intermediate completionHandler. Cleaner that way. Just an example here:

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: ((UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)!) {
    Use_it_here() {
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData)
        println("Background Fetch Complete")
    }
}

func Use_it_here(completionHandler: (() -> Void)!) {
    //....
    //DO IT
    //....
    completionHandler()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So since I was trying to query data into a tableview, my solution was to query the data, then simply reload the data. Very simple, no need for completion handlers

```
func getMathces(){
    let query = GTLQueryUser.queryForUserList()
    query.userBucket = "bucketname"
    service.executeQuery(query, completionHandler: {(ticket, response, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil{
            self._showErrorDialog(error)
            return
        }
        else{
            let userCollection = response as! GTLUserCollection
            if let newUsers = userCollection.items() as? [GTLUserUser]{
                for mat in newUsers[0].likedArray{
                    let name: String = (mat as? String)!
                    self.matches.append(name)
                }
            }
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```