# Cannot convert return expression of type () to return type WebImage?

Tags: swift, swiftui, closures

```
    internal func fetchConvoImage(for otherUserEmail: String, completion: @escaping (WebImage?) -> ()) {
let path = "images/\(otherUserEmail)_profile_picture.png"
StorageManager.shared.downloadURL(for: path) { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let url):
        
        completion(WebImage(url: url))
        
    case .failure(let error):
        print("failed to get other user image url: \(error)")
        completion(nil)
    }
}
```

}

```
internal func getConvoImage(for otherUserEmail: String) -> WebImage? {
fetchConvoImage(for: otherUserEmail) { image in
    if let image = image {
        return image
    } else {
        return nil
    }
    
}
```

}

I want to get the Image with the given URL using **SDWebImageSwiftUI** and return it back, but when I call the fetchConvoImage() and try to use the image received in the closure the system tells me **Cannot convert return expression of type () to return type WebImage?**

Comment: You're not returning anything from `getConvoImage` as the return is trapped inside of the closure for `fetchConvoImage`. You would have to use a closure to access the image. this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/45594135/5508175

Answer (score 0):

The closure from `getConvoImage` is returning a value when called within the closure passed by `fetchConvoImage` to the `StorageManager`, but you’re not passing that returned value back to `fetchConvoImage`. (e.g., the line `completion(WebImage(url: url))` calls `completion` but does not send it back to your fetch method).

You might try this:

```swift
func getConvoImage(for otherUserEmail: String) -> WebImage? {
    var result: WebImage?
    fetchConvoImage(for: otherUserEmail) { image in
        result = image
        return image
    }
    return result
}
```

That adds a `result` variable, local to `getConvoImage`, that has its value set inside the closure. Then, following the call to `fetchConvoImage` where the closure is used, the `result` will have been set, and can be returned.

I also reduced

```swift
if let image = image {
    return image
} else {
    return nil
}
```

to

```
return image
```

since the `if let ...` test is unnecessary in this case.