# Swift optional completion handler

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a service object in my Swift application to handle requests a bit easier. I've got most of it wired up, however I might be misunderstanding completion handlers.

I have this function that simply posts to a local API endpoint I have running.

```
func createList(name: String, completion: @escaping (Response) -> Void) {
        let parameters = ["name": name, "user_id": session.auth.currentUser!.uid]
        
        AF.request("\(url)/wishlist", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseDecodable(of: Response.self) { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .failure(let err):
                    print(err)
                case .success(let res):
                    completion(res)
            }
        }
    }
```

All that needs to happen is I need to pass that name to the function which I do here

```
barback.createList(name: name) -> after a button is tapped
```

However, I am now getting this error.

> Missing argument for parameter 'completion' in call

My goal here is to just return the `Response` object so I can access attributes on that to do certain things in the UI. I was not able to return `res` here because, from my understanding, this is an async request and it's actually returning from that competition handler? (could be butchering that). The way I saw others doing this was by adding a competition handler to the params and adding an escape to that.

My end goal here is to do something like...

```
if barback.createList(name: name).status = 200
    (trigger some UI component)
else
    (display error toast)
end
```

Is my function flawed in it's design? I've tried changing my competition handler to be

> completion: (@escaping (Response) -> Void) = nil

but run into some other errors there. Any guidance here?

Comment: Try `barback.createList(name: name) { if $0.status = 200 { ... } }`

Comment: @aheze this works...but why?

Comment: Because, as you yourself said, `createList` takes a completion handler. You forgot to supply it. aheze does supply it.

Comment: @Trenton as matt said [you need to supply it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68947022/14351818).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completion handlers are similar to function `return` values, but **not** the same. For example, compare the following functions:

```
/// 1. With return value
func createList(name: String) -> Response { }
```

```
/// 2. With completion handler
func createList(name: String, completion: @escaping (Response) -> Void) { }
```

In the first function, you'd get the return value instantly.

```
let response = barback.createList(name: name)
if response.status = 200 {
    /// trigger some UI component
}
```

However, if you try the same for the second function, you'll get the `Missing argument for parameter 'completion' in call` error. That's because, well, you defined a `completion:` argument label. However, you didn't supply it, as [matt commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68946912/swift-optional-completion-handler#comment121849712_68946912).

Think of completion handlers as "passing in" a chunk of code into the function, as a parameter. **You** need to supply that chunk of code. And from within that chunk of code, you can access your `Response`.

```
                                           /// pass in chunk of code here
barback.createList(name: name, completion: { response in
    /// access `response` from within block of code
    if response.status = 200 {
        /// trigger some UI component
    }
})
```

Note how you just say `barback.createList`, not `let result = barback.createList`. That's because in the second function, with the completion handler, doesn't have a return value (`-> Response`).

Swift also has a nice feature called [trailing closure syntax](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID102), which lets you omit the argument label `completion:`.

```
barback.createList(name: name) { response in
    /// access `response` from within block of code
    if response.status = 200 {
        /// trigger some UI component
    }
}
```

You can also refer to `response`, the closure's first argument, by using `$0` (which was what I did in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68946912/swift-optional-completion-handler/68947022#comment121849648_68946912)). But whether you use `$0` or supply a custom name like `response` is up to you, sometimes `$0` is just easier to type out.

```
barback.createList(name: name) {
    /// access $0 (`response`) from within block of code
    if $0.status = 200 {
        /// trigger some UI component
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `createList` would look something more like this:

```
barback.createList(name: name) { response in
    if response.status == 200 {
        // OK
    } else {
        // Error
    }
}
```

This fixes the issue because you are now running this `completion` closure - `{ response in ... }` - where `response` is the value you pass in. In this case, you pass in `res`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45594135/9607863) about using completion handlers.

---

If you did want an optional completion handler so you don't always need to include it, you could change the definition to the following (adding  `= { _ in }`, meaning it defaults to an empty closure):

```
func createList(name: String, completion: @escaping (Response) -> Void = { _ in })
```

Another way is actually making the closure optional:

```
func createList(name: String, completion: ((Response) -> Void)? = nil)
```

And then inside the method you need `?` when you call `completion`, since it's optional:

```
completion?(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the completion handler as mentioned in the comments and answers.
In addition you should include a completion when it fails, otherwise you
will never get out of that function.

I would restructure your code to cater for any errors that might happens, like this:

```
func createList(name: String, completion: @escaping (Response?, Error?) -> Void) {
    let parameters = ["name": name, "user_id": session.auth.currentUser!.uid]

    AF.request("\(url)/wishlist", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseDecodable(of: Response.self) { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .failure(let err):
            print(err)
            completion(nil, err)   
        case .success(let res):
            completion(res, nil)
        }
    }
}
```

call it like this:

```
barback.createList(name: name) { (response, error) in
    if error != nil {
        
    } else {
        
    }
}
```

If you do not put a completion(...) in your "case .failure" it will never get out of there.